# Handle events of all controls on a VB.net form from a class module

Tags: vb.net

I'm a beginner using VB.Net. I have a form and I need to handle the
events of all controls on a form by using an external class module.
How I can do this by passing to this class only the parameter form?
Thanks friends.

Comment: All events, or only certain ones?  Since all the controls on a form are exposed via its public `Controls` property, it's relatively easy to just loop through all of those and add an event handler on each one.  If you have nested controls, that's a little harder, but still doable.  But, if you want to handle *all* events, that would require some reflection.

Comment: Could you explain what the actual problem you're trying to solve is, instead of asking help implementing what you think the solution should be?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of messing around - this works.

Create your event handling class  either at the bottom of your main form file after `End Class` with all your event handling code - or in another file - it doesnt matter. As long as all your subs in the new class are declared with the shared keyword. - like this

```
Friend Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class OtherClass

    Public Shared Sub test2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("hi")
    End Sub

End Class
```

In your main code, you need to use addhandler to subscribe the code in your other class to the events - like this

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf otherclass.test2
End Sub
```

So now - based on the above code, when you click the button, a MessageBox will pop up showing **Hi**